# Calculate number of filtered Bigrams

Tags: nlp, nltk, python-3.7

Working on Hands on problems on NLP and got stuck in TASK given below.

Below are the statements which are required to be executed in sequence.

I have completed the below steps but the fresco platform is not accepting the solution.

Please let me know what I did wrong in the below code and steps

#### TASK

1.Import text corpus brown

2. Extract the list of words associated with text collections belonging to the
   **news** genre. Store the result in the variable **news_words**.
3. Convert each word of the list **news_words** into lower case, and store the
   result in **lc_news_words**.
4. Compute bigrams of the list **lc_news_words**, and store it in the variable
   **lc_news_bigrams**.
5. From **lc_news_bigrams**, filter bigrams where both words contain only
   alphabet characters. Store the result in **lc_news_alpha_bigrams**.
6. Extract the list of words associated with the corpus stopwords. Store the
   result in **stop_words**.
7. Convert each word of the list **stop_words** into lower case, and store the
   result in **lc_stop_words**.
8. Filter only the bigrams from **lc_news_alpha_bigrams** where the words are
   not part of **lc_stop_words**. Store the result in
   **lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams**.
9. Print the total number of filtered bigrams.

Below is the code which I have done so far. But fresco platform is not accepting the output.

```py
import nltk

import nltk.corpus

from nltk.corpus import brown

from nltk.util import bigrams

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

news_words = brown.words(categories='news')

lc_news_words  = [w.lower() for w in news_words]

lc_news_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(lc_news_words))

lc_news_alpha_bigrams = [(word1, word2) for word1, word2 in lc_news_bigrams if (word1.isalpha() and word2.isalpha()) ]

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

lc_stop_words = [w.lower() for w in stop_words ]

lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams = [ (w1, w2) for w1, w2 in lc_news_alpha_bigrams if (w1.lower() not in lc_stop_words and w2.lower() not in lc_stop_words) ] 

len((lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did everything correct, just remove the argument 'english' from

```py
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

stop_words = stopwords.words()
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

```py
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
news_words = [word for word in brown.words(categories = 'news')]
lc_news_words = [word.lower() for word in news_words]
len_news_words = [len(word) for word in lc_news_words]
news_len_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(len_news_words))
cfd_news = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(news_len_bigrams)
print(cfd_news[4][6])
lc_news_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(lc_news_words))
lc_news_alpha_bigrams = [(w1,w2) for w1,w2 in lc_news_bigrams if w1.isalpha() and w2.isalpha()]
stop_words  = stopwords.words()
lc_stop_words = [word.lower() for word in stop_words]
lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams = [(w1,w2) for w1,w2 in lc_news_alpha_bigrams if  not( (w1  in  lc_stop_words) or  (w2  in lc_stop_words ))]
print(len(lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams))
```

I have added code for both - task2 and task3 - as on the fresco platform, but the platform is not accepting it.

What may be the problem?

Comment: Logicwise above code is valid.It may be problem with Katacode .I have seen there is difference of 256 with actual answer and expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **and** instead of **or** in 
(w1  in  lc_stop_words) or  (w2  in lc_stop_words )

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
news_words     = brown.words(categories='news')
lc_news_words  = [l.lower() for l in news_words]
len_news_words = [len(w) for w in lc_news_words]
news_len_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(len_news_words))
cfd_news      = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(news_len_bigrams)
cfd_news.tabulate(conditions=[6,4])

lc_news_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(lc_news_words))
lc_news_alpha_bigrams = [(w1,w2) for w1,w2 in lc_news_bigrams if (w1.isalpha() and w2.isalpha())]
stop_words = stopwords.words()
lc_stop_words = [l.lower() for l in stop_words]
lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams = [ (w1, w2) for w1, w2 in lc_news_alpha_bigrams if (w1.lower() not in lc_stop_words and w2.lower() not in lc_stop_words) ]
print(len((lc_news_alpha_nonstop_bigrams)))
```

Final working code - Python 3